# how can i know the phone‘s electricity consumption

Tags: android, power-management

all.i want to know the phone‘s electricity cost in my apps.but the BatteryManager
can't give the information.how can i get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is not available via the Android SDK, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to really know is to hook up a power meter to your hardware to measure the current draw while your app is running.  The battery stats in the UI computed from an approximation over time based on the types of things the application is doing.